# Optimize an equity portfolio for the four central moments: problem formulation

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-selection, skewness, statistical-finance, kurtosis

Basically i am confused as to which formula to use for portfolio skew and kurtosis and how to use the same in the optimization problem. I would also like to know the options available regarding the software on which the optimization can be done.

### Edit

Based on [this post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58697/how-to-add-the-effect-of-skewness-in-the-portfolio-optimisation-objective-functi), we are able to include portfolio skewness, using the co-skewness matrix $M_3$, using a third-order Taylor series expansion, but how to also add in the minimization of portfolio skewness, $M_4$ (fourth-order Taylor expansion)?

$$\arg \max_w w^T\mu-\frac{1}{2}\gamma w^T\Sigma w+\frac{1}{6}\gamma^2 w^TM_3(w\otimes w)$$

Comment: What are you are doing to optimize for mean and standard deviation?

Comment: I think mean and standard deviation optimization can be done in excel itself, however its the other two that are difficult can you suggest some method, also i am not so clear on the formulae, it would be of great help if someone could tell me or at least show me a decent place to find the formulae

Comment: The mean - variance framework can be justified via a Taylor Expansion stopping  after the second step. Skew and Kurtosis can be included by expanding the Taylor approximation of the CE.